# Scale multiple object while keeping text size

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Whenever I scale multiple object, text size always gets scaled instead of only the text area.

Is there a way to preserve text size while rescaling multiple objects or groups?

For instance, I have one text area and a rectangle and I want to scale them both simultaneously. If I select one and ctrl-click the other and scale, then text gets squashed. If I only select the text and scale, then behavior is correct and only text area is scaled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternately, if you use the `Direct Selection Tool` (white arrow, keyboard shortcut <kbd>A</kbd>), you can select the whole rectangle, and just the frame portion of the text object by clicking just the edge of the text frame. You'll know you've just got the frame only selected if the text inside the frame is not underlined.

Text and frame are selected:

[image: Text selected - bad]

Frame only is selected:

[image: Frame selected - good]

Then you can scale your objects together, and the text inside the frame will not be distorted as result of the scaling.

Before scaling:

[image: Before scaling]

After scaling:

[image: After scaling]

Answer (score 0):

I would give every object a paragraph style and then reload the style for all of the objects at once after I'm done resizing.