# How Do I Set The Width Of Area Type In Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, text, transform

Once I have created Area Type, how do I adjust its width? Pulling on the handles allows me to resize it without distorting the text, but doesn't allow for fine-grained control. Typing a value into the transform palette gives me fine-grained control but caused distortion of the text.

**How can I set a new width (by typing) and without distorting the text?**

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/49429/15321). If you use the same selection method described there, you can type in the transform panel to specify exact size without distorting the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select your Area Text object and go to Type->Area Type Options...it'll bring up a dialog where you can change the width of the text box

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to be this exact with your text boxes you can draw a rectangle (M key) and then within the type tools (click and hold) there is a type inside shape version. Then click inside your rectangle.

There are also other ways to achieve this depending on the version of Illustrator you have. The latest versions have better control when it comes to text boxes.